# I am getting "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'" when I finish this code. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, typeerror

Here is the code

```
wagesAmount = float(input("Enter Wages Amount: "))

numberOfHours = float(input("Enter Number Of Hours Worked: "))

totalWagesAmount = (wagesAmount) * (numberOfHours)

if totalWagesAmount > "0":

   printtotalWagesAmount
```

I need to add an else statement as well but I was just trying to troubleshoot this issue first

Comment: Can you add a tag to indicate which programming language this is?

Comment: I added in 'python' I apologize

Comment: You are comparing a string and a number. Why do you have quotes on the 0?

Comment: I see what I need to do now. I removed the "" from the 0. Now I need to add an else statement to this and print the totalWagesAmount. I am new to all of this but this is very helpful.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. Speaking of, what do/don't you understand from the error? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"0" means it's a string . so when u wanna do if something > 0: thats means that 0 is integer and you say (if somthing > "0" string. so you

```
wagesAmount = float(input("Enter Wages Amount: "))

numberOfHours = float(input("Enter Number Of Hours Worked: "))

totalWagesAmount = (wagesAmount) * (numberOfHours)

if totalWagesAmount > 0:

    print (totalWagesAmount)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to all of this so I am just trying to learn what I am doing wrong and use stack overflow for help as well. If I wanted to add an else statement after the print for the if statement, would this work- else print"Invalid input" ?

Comment: I'm new to and learning Django. doing blog and forum you should try . and try to build some real projects you will learn lot of things trust me

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `""` on `0` because `"0" != 0`

```
if totalWagesAmount > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing "0" means its string because of dynamic typing in python.

Comment: `"0"` having quotes doesn't really have anything to do with dynamic typing.